Where in the iOS document or available source does it say that TaskPriority.userInitiated and TaskPriority.high are aliases?
I have heard this bit a few times. From a WWDC talk I think as well as through this Hacking with Swift article.

The highest priority is .high, which is synonymous with
.userInitiated. As the name implies, this should be used only for
tasks that the user specifically started and is actively waiting for.

However I am struggling to back this one up with actual Apple documentation. Where could I find it?

It is not documented. They happen to be the same (and as matt demonstrates, this is easy to show), but this is not promised.

Actually I'm surprised that userInitiated isn't among the deprecated names.

A TaskPriority is just a number. So simply run this code:
print(TaskPriority.userInitiated.rawValue)
print(TaskPriority.high.rawValue)

See? They are both names for the same number (25).
